# howto "addClass" if value not exist on page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

i'm trying to add a css class to a field "specia"l if another selector"normal" not exists.

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('.normal').length) {
    $('#special').addClass("yellowstone");  }
});
}(jQuery));
```

the code above is not working.
what is wrong?

EDIT:

the purpose is if there exists in the html-code a

```
<span class="normal">whatevervalue</span>
```

that this happens:

```
<div id="special" class="yellowtone">blablablah<div>
```

if not it should be

```
<div id="special">blablablah<div>
```

Comment: That says if there are any elements *with* the class "normal" - that is, 1 or more elements were found so length is *more than* 0 and thus  a truth-y value - then do .. not sure if that is what is desired as the wording is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: you add the class if the .normal element exists, instead if it does not, so try if($('.normal').length == 0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Negate your if statement:

```
if (!$('.normal').length) {
    $('#special').addClass("yellowstone");  }
});
```

Note the **`!`**

Answer (score 0):

*if normal not exist*

```
 if ($('.normal').length === 0) {
    $('#special').addClass("yellowstone");
 }
```